# Python - XY array from 2 lists

Tags: python, arrays, list

I've 2 lists :

```
x = [1, 2, 3, 4, ...]
y = [11, 12, 13, 14, ...]
```

And I would like to obtain an array like this :

```
XY = [ [1,11] , [2,12], ... [xN,yN] ]
```

To create a plot like this: [How to draw line inside a scatter plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981696/how-to-draw-line-inside-a-scatter-plot)

Comment: A list with tuples would be a better for you, than a list of lists. zip(x,y) will do that for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip(X,Y)` gave you a tuple , so if you want a nested list you need to convert the tuples to list and concatenate them ! you can do it with the `map` function !

```
x = [1,2,3,4, ...]
y = [11,12,13,14, ...]

XY=map(list,zip(x,y))
```

Demo:

```
>>> x = [1,2,3,4]
>>> y = [11,12,13,14]
>>> zip(x,y)
[(1, 11), (2, 12), (3, 13), (4, 14)]
>>> map(list,zip(x,y))
[[1, 11], [2, 12], [3, 13], [4, 14]]
```

Comment: you answer is better dude ;)

Answer (score 3):

you can use `zip` like this:

```
XY = zip(x, y)
```

And if you want nasted list you can use:

```
XY = [list(a) for a in zip(x, y)]
```